# How to sum only common rows based on the filter dynamically using DAX in Power Bi?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have this little schema attached in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKvEb.png)

Following is the sample data and I want to only get the common rows that all the selected contractors from filter have selected.

```
Item_id itemcode    target_bid_price    contractors
1       abc-001     1000                asher
2       abc-002     2000                asher
4       abc-004     4000                asher
1       abc-001     1000                hammad
2       abc-002     2000                hammad
**3     abc-003     3000                hammad**
4       abc-004     4000                hammad
1       abc-001     1000                jawad
2       abc-002     2000                jawad
**3     abc-003     3000                jawad**
4       abc-004     4000                jawad
```

[I have this little schema attached in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKvEb.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this measure as filter and select non blank values.

```
Measure = 
VAR t =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            SUMMARIZE(
                'tbl'
                ,tbl[Item_id]
                ,tbl[itemcode]
                ,tbl[target_bid_price]
            )
            ,"ContractorsCount",CALCULATE(CountROWS(VALUES(tbl[contractors])),ALL(tbl[contractors]))
        )
        ,ALL(tbl[contractors])
    )
VAR currentContractorsQty=
                        CountROWS(
                            CALCULATETAble(
                                VALUES(tbl[contractors])
                                ,ALLSELECTED()
                            )
                        )
VAR Result =
    FILTER(
        t
        ,[ContractorsCount]=currentContractorsQty
    )
RETURN 
    COUNTROWS(Result)
```